# Помогите с Visual Code и кодом Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Я всегда использовал Visual Code и никаких проблем не было.Но сегодня,почему в отладке мне не показываются русские символы,переискал весть интернет[image: y] нечего не понял,надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решений может быть несколько, но перед этим надо так же понимать, что кодировка в программе и сохраненного файла должны совпадать, если они не совпадают, то будет такое.

**1. Решение**
Смените для начала кодировку в VSC
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого откройте файл с кодом в блокноте (или любом другом текстовом редакторе) и сохраните еще раз с той же кодировкой, что в VSC.
После этого так же можно поменять кодировку в консоли

Answer (score 2):

Проблема заключается в кодировке. Сами строки никакой кодировки не имеют, поскольку хранятся в binary, но их отображение зависит от выбранной кодировки. Обычно проблемы возникают при отображения криллических символов. Так строка "привет" в разных кодировках имеет разное представление в binary.

```
>>> "привет".encode('cp1251')
b'\xef\xf0\xe8\xe2\xe5\xf2'
>>> "привет".encode('utf-8')
b'\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82'
```

Попробуйте **сменить кодировку vscode** в нижней панели рабочего окна, либо в ручную отображать строку в нужной кодировке.

```
>>> str_encoded = "привет".encode('cp1251')
>>> str_encoded.decode('cp1251')
```

Comment: Проблема в том,что в коде отображается все норм,а в отладке такая дичь,а к примеру в консоли отладки тоже норм показывается,именно в отладке кодировка слетает. Не знаю что с этим делать.